# Functionality of the site is changing when launched via selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i am testing the registration  functionality of an application.If the requires fields are left blank and if we  try to click on the registration button then an alert box appears showing the error message.
        i have written the script to handle the alert boxes but When i execute the  script the alert boxes are not appearing instead the the same error message is shown in red color at the top of the page or  this message appears "
Email already exist please User another Email" even if all the fields are left blank.Those error messages appear only when the site is opened via script.

```
   While some times the alert boxes appear for just a half second or less and the script throws UnhandledAlertException.
```

I can't share the site details.Here is the part of a script i have written

```
  WebElement fname = driver.findElement(By.id("fname"));
  fname.sendKeys("");
   driver.findElement(By.id("registration")).click();
    if(fname.getAttribute("value").equals("")) {
      Alert al=d.switchTo().alert();
       al.accept();
   }
```

Could  any one explain to me this kind of behavior of the site.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of sending blank, you can clear the email textfield**. That way, it will be cleaner and also confirm that the textfield is blank and the alert popup will come up, each time hence.

You can use the below code for clearing the email textfield:

```
WebElement email=d.findElement(By.id("email"));
email.clear();
```

### Code for Accepting alert:-

The below code will **wait for 20 seconds for the alert to come up, and then accept it.**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("registration")).click(); 
try{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
    Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    alert.accept();
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error found while accepting alert: "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.i have tried what u said above but still the same problem.It is throwing UnhandledAlertException and showing error at this line email.getAttribute("value").while the same worked for other sites

Comment: yes the alert is coming up.Even though the code is written to handle the code it is throwing the UnhandledAlertException.The Script is showing error at this line in the script    String str=fname.getAttribute("value").And also why the working of the site is changing when launched through the script

Comment: @user3660822: Please try the edited code above for accepting alert, and see if that helps.

Comment: I have tried ur code but still the same .As i have told the error is pointed at String str=fname.getAttribute("value").I don't understand why it is showing error at this line.I think after this line the code is not executed may be  that's the reason for the Exception

Comment: As you said **" While some times the alert boxes appear for just a half second or less and the script throws UnhandledAlertException"**, I suspect it might not be an alert after all, because a [javascript alert popup](http://www.htmlite.com/JS002.php) won't close unless it is accepted/dismissed. Please verify if it is, in fact, an alert pop up or just a notification that closes in a few seconds.

Comment: I have tried by removing the if condition and only with these lines                                                         Alert al=d.switchTo().alert();
       al.accept();then the code is excuted fine and the alert box is also accepted

Comment: i have verified with the corresponding team the script for the application is written in jquery.So it is a javascript alert

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the alert box you are mentioning?  For now, you can't add a screenshot because your rep is tad low. [Upload in imgur](http://imgur.com/) and share the link here. It will then be easier to comprehend, what exactly you are getting at. Furthermore, if the alert, as you say, remains for few seconds, then I don't think there is a need to accept it, as it is already getting closed on its own. Or, Do you want to assert the presence of alert  ?